# Full group by query similar to mysql

Tags: kibana

Sample mysql query:

```
select error_number, query, count(*) as cnt from mytable group by error_number;
```

This query works in mysql even if both the columns (error_number and query) are not part of aggregation. It shows a random record for "*query*" column in such cases.

This does not seem to be possible in Kibana. I have to group by error_number AND query. I want to group by only error_number and still see a random "query" column from that group.

Is it possible in Kibana? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the max value query for each error number counts as being random, then you can try the following query:

```
select
    error_number,
    max(query) as query,
    count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by error_number;
```